# Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, unsafe

I am working on a cross platform application that targets Android and iOS platforms. I am using jQuery 1.9.1, Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 and Phonegap 2.8.0.

I want to send an ajax request and set the request headers "Connection" and "Keep-Alive". On Android Phones with OS greater than 4.1 (Whose default browser is Chrome) I get an error which says "Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"".

I am able to send such requests on lower end devices and even on iPhones.

Can Anyone Please help me out.

I have to set these 2 headers in the request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing same issue in android 4.4
did you find any solution for this yet ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX post error : Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)

Comment: Unfortunately, XMLHttpRequest doesn't allow you to reuse the same connection for multiple requests, as doing so could bypass security checks.  Older browsers that allows this are probably broken.

Answer (score 3):

Section [4.6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) of the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 1 spec lists headers that "are controlled by the user agent" and not allowed to be set with the `setRequestHeader()` method.  Both `Connection` and `Keep-Alive` are in that list.

```
Accept-Charset
Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Connection
Content-Length
Cookie
Cookie2
Date
DNT
Expect
Host
Keep-Alive
Origin
Referer
TE
Trailer
Transfer-Encoding
Upgrade
User-Agent
Via
```

Comment: how to fix that  ?