# Process Uploaded file on web server without storing locally first?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am trying to process the user uploaded file real time on the websever, 
but it seems, APACHE invokes PHP, only once complete file is uploaded.

When i uploaded the file using CURL, and set

> Transfer-Encoding : "Chunked"

I had some success, but can't do same thing via browser.

- I used Dropzone.js but when i tried to set same header, it said Transfer -Encoding is an unsafe header, hence not setting it.

This answer explains what is the issue there.
[Can't set Transfer-Encoding :"Chunked from Browser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481945/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)

**In a Nutshell problem is , when a user uploads the file to webserver, i want webserver to start processing it as soon as first byte is available.
by process i mean, PIPING it to a Named Pipe.**

Dont want 500mb first getting uploaded to a server, then start processing it.

But with current Webserver (APACHE - PHP), I cant seem to be able to accomplish it.

could someone please explain, what technology stack or workarounds to use, so that i can upload the large file via browser and start processing it, as soon as first byte is available.

Comment: you can do it via node js if you interested I can post answer

Comment: Can you upload to Amazon AWS in chunk of 5 MB using fineuploader and initiate one cron to check new AWS file and process it for Named Pipe?

Comment: @bxN5 : yes please post, currently i am trying to do same with busboy library, on 'data' function i am piping the chunk to child process..!

Comment: @ChetanPatel : i dont intend to stream to AWS, i want to stream to an external app, for example tshark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use NodeJS/Multiparty to do that. [Here](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/blob/master/examples/s3.js) they have an example of a direct upload to Amazon S3. [This](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/blob/master/examples/s3.js#L29) is the form, which sets content type to `multipart/form-data`. And [here](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/blob/master/examples/s3.js#L39) is the function for form parts processing. `part` parameter is of type `ReadableStream`, which will allow per-chunk processing of the input using `data` event.

More on readable streams in node js is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want that (sorry don`t think thats a good idea) you should try looking for a FUSE Filesystem which does your job.

Maybe there is already one https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Filesystems

Or you should write your own.

But remember as soon as the upload is completed and the post script finishes his job the temp file will be deleted

Comment: I am afraid , this is not what i am looking for.
i just want to stream the uploaded file to an external app, without storing it first.

Answer (score 1):

you can upload file with html5 resumable upload tools (like Resumable.js) and process uploaded parts as soon as they received.

or as a workaround , you may find the path of uploaded file (usually in /tmp) and then write a background job to stream it to 3rd app. it may be harder.

there may be other solutions...