# Salesforce Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

Tags: javascript, ajax, salesforce

I am trying to create a user login/signup on my remote app that accesses user data on Salesforce. I am doing this from javascript via Salesforce REST API. This was not working using requests straight from javascript due to CORS restrictions, so I found [this example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13607/how-to-call-apex-rest-api-from-javascript?rq=1). My code is as follows:

```
    var result = sforce.connection.login('example@provider.com', 'pass'+'securityToken');
    sforce.connection.init(result.sessionId, 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token')

    sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
        url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        requestHeaders: {
            "Authorization" : "Bearer " +__sfdcSessionId,
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Connection":"Keep-Alive"
        },
        method: "GET",
        onSuccess : function(response) {
            console.log("Success " + response)
        },
        onFailure: function(response) {
            console.log("Failed " + response)
        }
    });
```

When I run this code I get the following errors:

1) Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
2) POST http:///services/Soap/u/31.0 404 (Not Found)
3) Remote invocation failed, due to:

```
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /services/Soap/u/31.0 was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
 status code:
```

Using a code editor I can see that the errors are occurring after hitting the sforce.connection.login() script and never making it to the sforce.connection.init() script in my code.

How do I resolve this issue so that I may log a user in from my remote web app and gain access to the user information within salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

It seem your issue is like the one in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)

XMLHttpRequest isn't allowed to set these headers, they are being set automatically by the browser. The reason is that by manipulating these headers you might be able to trick the server into accepting a second request through the same connection, one that wouldn't go through the usual security checks - that would be a security vulnerability in the browser.