# XMLHttpRequest no return value

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

i am unable to receive a response from the php file.

Javascript

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost/php_bollywood_romance.php";
var params = "film="+movie_name_entered;
http.open("POST", url, true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

I have even tried to do this.....

```
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if ("withCredentials" in http)
 {
    var url = "http://localhost/php_bollywood_romance.php";
var movie_name_entered="hi";
var params = "film="+movie_name_entered;
http.open("POST", url, true);
 }
 else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
    http = new XDomainRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost/php_bollywood_romance.php";
    var movie_name_entered="hi";
    var params = "film="+movie_name_entered;
    http.open("POST", url);
} else {
    http = null;
}
if (http){
http.onload = function(){
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.write(http.responseText);
        callback(http.responseText);
        alert("hey");
    }
}
http.send(params);
};
```

PHP

```
  <?php
    {
     $name = $_POST["film"];
      $file ='data_bollywood_romance.txt';
       $current=file_get_contents($file); //gets existing content from the file
    $current ="$current \n $name \n";
   file_put_contents($file,$current); //put newstuff
    echo 'hi';
   return 'yes';
     }
   ?>
```

However this also does not seem to work... if i do alert("http.response") after http.send(params)...it alerts an alert with nothing written on it. I thought this might be because there is same origin policy problem so i tried to do Cross-domain Ajax with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing but that didnt work either( that is the second code). Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: First thing is inspect your browsers developer console and look at the raw response of the request. First you need to establish that your PHP is sending output.

Comment: how do we know if php is sending output

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set this two headers:

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

[Previous thread about your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)

I tried it without and worked fine.

Personally i would go all the way using jQuery Ajax, but thats just "lazy me" :)

Comment: i tried jQuery ajax but that didnt work for me. I even removed the two headers but that is not working

Comment: Well, you'll need to do some debuging... Open Chrome javascript console and check for errors thrown when making the Ajax request first.

Comment: Depending on what console tells you, you may have to explicitly allow requests on php script with something like this `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: BTW: I only tested the 1st script, removing the offending headers. Did't try the 2nd one you posted.