# XMLHttpRequest not working on button click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am developing this chrome extension and I have the backend on Django. I am doing an XMLHttpRequest POST to login the user. When I call the function on 'DOMContentLoaded', it works. However, when I do it on a button click, it doesn't work.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function login(){
    //alert("hello");
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "someURL";
    //var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    //var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = "email=someEmail&password=Password";
    //alert(params);
    //var params = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //alert(http.responseText);
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

Now, when I do this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    login();
});
```

It works. On clicking the extension, I get a success message.

However, when I do this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", login);
});
```

It doesn't work.

Here is the `popup.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <form>
                <input type="email" id="email">
                <input type="password" id="password">
                <button id="btn">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "payback",
  "description": "payback.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/", "https://*/"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/", "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give a better description of what happens instead of "it doesn't work"? Consider that you can debug your code by right-clicking the browser action button and selecting "Inspect popup"

Comment: @Xan By "it doesn't work" I mean I don't get the alert. Placing an alert(http.responseText) just before the if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) statement, I get an empty alert. I tried the "Inspect popup" thing but nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: It is not advisable to use `alert()` in a popup, since it makes it lose focus and potentially vanish. Use `console.log()` + inspect to debug.

Comment: @Xan I tried using console.log(). Still nothing shows up in the log.

Comment: Very strange. I guess `login` is not even called for some reason. Double-check your element IDs for typos.

Comment: Yes strange indeed. I have put a console.log statement at the starting of the login function. even that is not being displayed. The console does show a red cross mark(which it shows for errors at the top) for a split second and then goes away. Is there a way the popup might be getting refreshed on it's own or something?

Comment: Have you tried the following: document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", login()); or document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {login();}); Think you might be missing the parenthesis.

Comment: @David For callbacks without parameters the latter is equivalent to `addEventListener('click', login)`. But the former is just plain wrong, because the "callback" will be executed before the event listener fires.

Comment: @devnull69 You are absolutely right. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Remove lines

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

XMLHttpRequest isn't allowed to set these headers, they are being set automatically by the browser. [Read this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection).

Also use

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Login"/>
```

instead of

```
<button id="btn">Login</button>
```

because button will submit form itself.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a click on a `<button>` will submit the form (because the default type is `submit`). Try this

```
<button id="btn" type="button">Login</button>
```