# Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" extjs4

Tags: javascript, post, extjs, extjs4

I try to post data with extjs 4 but i am getting  Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" this exeption.

this is function that i used to post data.

```
function postDataAsParamsINN(params, url, success, failure, comp) {
    if (comp) {
        comp.getEl().mask('Loading...');
    }
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : url,
        method : 'POST',
        params : params,
        headers : {'Connection':'close'},
        success : function(response, opts) {
            if (comp)
                comp.getEl().unmask();

            var resp = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (success)
                success(resp);
        },
        failure : function(response, opts) {
            if (comp)
                comp.getEl().unmask();

            if (failure)
                failure(response);
            else {
                showDefaultFailureMsgINN();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this is how i use it.

```
text : 'Get Forms',
                    iconCls : 'button-with-icon icon-search',
                    id : 'btnGetForms',
                    disabled : false,
                    handler : function(btn, pressed) {
                        if(flightId == null){
                            Ext.Msg.alert("Please select a Flight to see its forms")
                        }
                        else{                                                         

postDataAsParamsINN({flightId:flightId},flightFormListUrl,function(resp){                       
                                Ext.Msg.alert("show the forms with flight id : " + flightId + resp.succes)
                                });
                            }
                        }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax requests are not allowed to set the Connection header. See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection).

Remove this line:

```
headers : {'Connection':'close'},
```

You shouldn't have any issues then, why are you trying to set it? I think it should only be showing as a warning as the browser should just ignore it. Different browsers may treat it differently.