# Refused to set unsafe header "cookie" and net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, cookies, access-token

I am trying to make REST request on Wildfly server. First I must login to old application and to get cookie. That cookie must be used in newer application 
which makes REST requests. New application is some template from real existing one. I have tried some options in header of REST request like setting properties withCredentials, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, token, crossDomain as shown in function getAllEntities bellow.

REST requests where tested and they worked fine with RestClient on Firefox browser as shown bellow.

I do not know how to:

- insert cookie which I get from previous application
- remove token (it seems this is impossible)
- solve these two errors which are written in title

This is how does request look like in RestClient:

```
Method: GET 
URL: https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/api/codes
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cookie: code_system_frontend=bvkkvbcp24igdgja4h5hht13p4; code=ae8be9267e8dfea86a8f54f6bd980733
```

This is how response look like in RestClient:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Accept, responseType, X-MAC, X-TIME, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Accept
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2016 15:22:00 GMT
Server: WildFly/9
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
access-control-allow-credentials: true
x-powered-by: Undertow/1
```

and typical JSON response body:

```
[
    {
        "code": 1,
        "codename": "Demo"
    },
    {
       "code": 2,
       "codename": "Gmx"
    }
    //AND SO ON 
]
```

This is code in Angularjs:

```
function getAllEntities(entityName, addToCache) {
    config = {
       headers: {

                'cookie':'code_system_frontend=bvkkvbcp24igdgja4h5hht13p4;code=ae8be9267e8dfea86a8f54f6bd980733',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'withCredentials':'true',
                //'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                //'X-API-TOKEN': undefined,
                //'token':undefined,
                //crossDomain: true
            },
            data: ''
        };

        return $http.get(endPoints.api + entityName, config)
            .then(getAllEntitiesComplete)
            .catch(function (message) {
                exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getAllEntities for entity ' + entityName)(message);
                return $q.reject(message);
                logger.info('Message ' + message);
            });

        function getAllEntitiesComplete(data, status, headers, config) {

            var entities = data.data;

            if (addToCache) {
                service.cachedLookups[entityName] = entities;
                service[entityName + 's'] = entities;
            }
            return entities;
        }
    }
```

In Firebug I get:

Request Header in Firebug:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/json
Host: XX.XX.XX.XX:8443
Origin http://admin.dev.xxxxxxxx.xxx
Referer http://admin.dev.xxxxxxxx.xxx/xx/codes
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
token fake token for anonymous user 
withCredentials true
```

And I also get warning in Firebug:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resource at https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/xxxxxxxx/api/code. (Reason: 
CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*').
```

And I get this error because of my code:

```
Error: XHR Failed for getAllEntities for entity suborder Object { status=0, config={...},  data=null,  more...}
```

In Crome I get:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"
```

and

```
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the  remote resource at https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/xxxxxxxx/api/code.
>   (Reason:  CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match
>   '*').

It seems like you have not enabled Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on your server or that it's wrongly configured.

Regarding the header issue, you should have a look at that post:

[AJAX post error : Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection)

> XMLHttpRequest isn't allowed to set these headers, they are being set
>   automatically by the browser. The reason is that by manipulating these
>   headers you might be able to trick the server into accepting a second
>   request through the same connection, one that wouldn't go through the
>   usual security checks - that would be a security vulnerability in the
>   browser.

If you are using cookies, the cookie should automatically be sent with each request, particularly if you have set withCredentials = true.

If you are using tokens however, you must add them to the Authorization header, generally in the format: "Bearer " + mytoken