# Ajax Jquery Websocket handshare request headers - Refused to set unsafe header

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, websocket

I am using jquery to make a WebSocket handshake request. Here is the code

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://'+ document.location.host + '/handshake',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
      },
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Upgrade', 'websocket');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'Upgrade');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Key', 'dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13');
      },
      success: function (result) {
        // CallBack(result);
      },
      error: function (error) {

      }
    });
```

I tried setting headers within `headers` section also, but I still get the below error and headers are not set in the handshake request.

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers says that handshake is the very first request that client(browser) makes

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX post error : Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210507/ajax-post-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-connection) seems to be related.

I believe if you want to make a WebSocket handshake upgrade request, you can use the `WebSocket` object native to Javascript to do what you need (it sends the request, implicitly setting headers):

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/yourURL');

    webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
        //Handle the error event, ('error' in your code)
    };

    webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
        //Handle what happens when the connection is made ('success' in your code)
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
       //What do do on each message
    };
```

With your code, you are simply not allowed to touch those headers.