# Making a POST request to Tumblr's API inside a Chrome Extension

Tags: post, oauth, google-chrome-extension, tumblr

I'm trying to make a text post to Tumblr using their API and chrome_ex_oauth.

- API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting
- chrome_ex_oauth: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html

The whole process of getting authorized works. What I can't get to work is doing a POST. I'm doing the following:

**Edit: I've updated the code to reflect Rob W's correct suggestion about the body field**

```
var stringify = function (parameters) {
  var params = [];
  for(var p in parameters) {
    params.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' +
                encodeURIComponent(parameters[p]));
  }
  return params.join('&');
};

var onAuthorized = function() {
  var url = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/jindie.tumblr.com/post';
  var request = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers':{
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': stringify({
      'type': 'text',
      'state': 'draft',
      'title': 'Test post...',
      'body': 'Hello, World!'
    })
  };

  oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, function(responseText, xhr){alert(responseText);}, request);
};

oauth.authorize(onAuthorized);
```

I've been examining the code, and thinking what could be wrong, but I seriously have no idea. Do you?

Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When the documentation doesn't help have a look at the source code, [`chrome_ex_oauth.js`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/oauth_contacts/chrome_ex_oauth.js?content-type=text/plain).

You have to use `'body'` instead of `'parameters'`:

```
var request = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'body': {
```

### Debugging

In order to find the cause, I followed these steps (annotated my thoughts):

1. Apparently, the post body is empty. So, the implementation of the API must be wrong.
2. Ctrl + F `sendSignedRequest`:

   ```
   ChromeExOAuth.prototype.sendSignedRequest = function(url, callback, opt_params) {
     var method = opt_params && opt_params['method'] || 'GET';
     var body = opt_params && opt_params['body'] || null;
     var params = opt_params && opt_params['parameters'] || {};
     var headers = opt_params && opt_params['headers'] || {};

     var signedUrl = this.signURL(url, method, params);

     // Hmm...? Where is `params` being passed...?
     ChromeExOAuth.sendRequest(method, signedUrl, headers, body, function (xhr) {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         callback(xhr.responseText, xhr);
       }
     });
   };
   ```
3. `signURL` doesn't modify `params`, so that's not a problem.
4. Ctrl + F `sendRequest`:

   ```
   ChromeExOAuth.sendRequest = function(method, url, headers, body, callback) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
       callback(xhr, data);
     }
     xhr.open(method, url, true);
     if (headers) { . . . }
     xhr.send(body); // <-- !!!
   };
   ```
5. Got it! **`body` has to be used instead of `parameters`.**
6. Backtracks the `body` variable to the **`request['body']`** (see 2).

Comment: Great that you took the time to jot down how you arrived at the conclusion.

Comment: Great detailed response. Thank you. However, changing from 'parameters' to 'body' didn't seem to work either. I'm still getting the same error response.

Comment: @Sparragus Have you already tried adding the `Content-Length` header? The value has to be equal to the size of the body.

Comment: I just added `Content-Length` and started getting a different error: `{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}` I'm allowing my application on Tumblr (using the oauth procedure). I will double check my keys and debug why this is happening.

Comment: @RobW I just noticed this error: `Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"` [The reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623963/webkit-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-content-length) seems to be security.