# No callback from a API call to Tumblr

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-chrome-extension, tumblr

I'm making a chrome extension, which needs to get the current user's followers. The tumblr API says that I need to implement oauth and send requests as listed [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-followers). I implemented oauth following the example and using the library from google [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html).

So, the result was that the `oauth.authorize` function would run, but the callback function, `onFollowers`, wouldn't be called, leaving me to believe that I'm not getting a response from tumblr for some reason.

This is the code I ended up with:

background.html:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
  'request_url' : 'POST http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
  'authorize_url' : 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize',
  'access_url' : 'POST http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token',
  'consumer_key' : '[key provided]',
  'consumer_secret' : '[secret provided]',
  'app_name' : '[app name]'
});

var followers = null;
var baseHostname = localStorage.getItem('BaseHostname');

function onFollowers(text, xhr) {
    //parsing JSON response
}

function getFollowers() {
  oauth.authorize(function() {
    var url = "api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+baseHostname+"/followers";
    oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, onFollowers, {
      'parameters' : {
        'base-hostname' : baseHostname
      }
    });
  });
};

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "getFollowers")
      console.log(baseHostname);
      getFollowers();
      sendResponse({farewell: "getFollowers function run success"});
  });
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

See here:
[Making a POST request to Tumblr's API inside a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568812/making-a-post-request-to-tumblrs-api-inside-a-chrome-extension)

Could be that you

> sendSignedRequest

Should have the params the other way around? First **method**, than **url** ?

Comment: No, I checked the library I'm using. that's the correct order. URL, then methord.