# AWS API signed POST request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, amazon-kinesis

What I'm trying to do: 
Ultimately: I want to populate an AWS Kinesis stream from a browser extension (Safari, Chrome).
I need to send the request to AWS using a signing process (v4); this involves setting headers and encrypting them (on a distant server with the aws secret key) to finally join those to the request.

Amazon requests the header "Host" to be explicitly defined…
However Javascript strictly disallow setting it (and a bunch of others, for good reasons)

I must be missing something—how can I do this?

sources:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html - the example is in Python but it shows how server-side they intend to use the Host header

notes: I'm currently using POST; the example's comments describing the GET and query string mention the "Host" as well: it must exist as a header in the request

also: Using a similar setup, I managed to have a file uploaded from the client directly to an S3 bucket–the autorisation process is slightly different (no requirement for 'Host').

Comment: You might want to check out the AWS SDK (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#putRecord-property) to make it easier to work with AWS services and Kinesis specifically.

Comment: Thanks @Guy i actually cant use the sdk as the back end runs on Parse.com so i had to build things from scratch.

Comment: How could you manage to upload a file to s3 without mentioning "host" in headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Host:` header is being filled in and parsed from the given URL by the JS XHR itself when you execute it, same as with `curl`, e.g.

```
curl -v -X POST http://example.org/foo
```

...will automatically add the header `Host: example.org`...

For AWS you'll still need to add it to the `canonical_headers` list for signing though (and in all lowercase), as described in your linked example. That part has nothing to do with actually establishing a connection though.