# JS: Processing form as a POST but retrieving as a GET?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Retrieving the data with PHP, I cannot use `$_POST`; but `$_GET`. Why? Am I sending my form data incorrectly?

I'd have thought `request.open("POST"` would process the form as a POST and not GET? How may I sent it as a POST?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST","email.php?text=" + textarea.value + "&email=" + email.value, true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var resp = request.responseText;

        console.log(resp);

    }
};

request.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're adding data inside the `URL`.

Change your request to:

```
request.open("POST","email.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 2); // 2 here is the no. of params to send
....


request.send("text=" + textarea.value + "&email=" + email.value);
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Makes sense. So I'd add the parameters to request.send()?

Comment: Please also use http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are sending the variables in the url that is why you are getting in get. See this example post

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny"; // all prams variable here
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623963/webkit-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-content-length says there is no need to set a content length or connection.