# Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery in SharePoint online

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, jquery-file-upload, sharepoint-online

I am using the Code example 1: Upload a file across SharePoint domains by using the REST API and jQuery described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx.

This is the code :

```js
'use strict';

var appWebUrl, hostWebUrl;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
    }

    // Get the add-in web and host web URLs.
    appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

});

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
function uploadFile() {

    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    // The display name must be unique every time you run the example.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

    // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    var getFile = getFileBuffer();
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

        // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
        addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

            // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
            var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert('file uploaded and updated');
                });
                changeItem.fail(onError);
            });
            getItem.fail(onError);
        });
        addFile.fail(onError);
    });
    getFile.fail(onError);

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')?@target='{3}'",
            appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }

    // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
    function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

        // Construct the endpoint.
        // The list item URI uses the host web, but the cross-domain call is sent to the
        // add-in web and specifies the host web as the context site.
        fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace(hostWebUrl, '{0}');
        fileListItemUri = fileListItemUri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');

        var listItemAllFieldsEndpoint = String.format(fileListItemUri + "?@target='{1}'",
            appWebUrl, hostWebUrl);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: listItemAllFieldsEndpoint,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }

    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
    function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

        // Construct the endpoint.
        // Specify the host web as the context site.
        var listItemUri = itemMetadata.uri.replace('_api/Web', '_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web');
        var listItemEndpoint = String.format(listItemUri + "?@target='{0}'", hostWebUrl);

        // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
        // For simplicity, also use the name as the title.
        // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
        // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
        var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
            itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

        // Send the request and return the promise.
        // This call does not return response content from the server.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: listItemEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length": body.length,
                "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}

// Get parameters from the query string.
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

```html
        <input id="getFile" type="file" /><br />
        <input id="displayName" type="text" value="Enter a unique name" /><br />
        <input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadFile()" />
```

Update: 
This is the error for the 403 Forbidden error:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCyC8.png)

Comment: I just edited the question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebKit "Refused to set unsafe header 'content-length'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623963/webkit-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-content-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log and check values of following values exists and passes correctly.

- appWebUrl
- serverRelativeUrlToFolder
- fileName
- hostWebUrl

```js
console.log(appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);
// Construct the endpoint.
var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')?@target='{3}'",
            appWebUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName, hostWebUrl);
```

Then check whether those resources are available in the SharePoint. If you still finding this issue. Feel free to bug me back.

This link may usefull - [File attachment using SharePoint REST API](https://kushanlahiru.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/file-attach-to-sharepoint-2013-list-custom-using-angular-js-via-rest-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to set these headers in your ajax request, they are being set automatically by the browser. 
remove  `"content-length": body.length,` from your Ajax call

Comment: Tried that and the first error is gone but now I still have the 403 Forbidden Error.
P.s this is from a web part.

Comment: your login credentials are not properly added so the site is rejecting your request

Comment: I am the site owner for that SharePoint site... I updated the screenshot error on the question post.