# how to resolve Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to build an json/javascript interface to check emails on haveibeenpwned.

However, when trying to set the header, I get an error (in developer tools):

> jquery-1.10.2.js:8699 Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/mark@fixitks.co.uk',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
      error: function() { alert('boo!'); }
      ,
      headers: {
  'User-Agent': 'uaheader'
}
    });
  });
```

I can run similar code from C# in the browser without any issues, but not in Javascript.

Is there anyway around this.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: the browser will restrict you from setting that on an ajax call.

Comment: thanks - can I do it from just Javascript in that case, if I don't use ajax - or would that be restricted too?

Comment: ajax is javascript - jquery is just wrapping that. theres nothing you can do directly from the browser

Comment: ... or rather directly from JS. You can override the userAgent string in Chrome's dev tools, in FF you've to set it in about: configurations.

Comment: "jquery-1.10.2.js" — **Danger** jQuery 1.x is no longer supported and has known security problems. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebKit "Refused to set unsafe header 'content-length'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623963/webkit-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-content-length)

Answer (score 2):

There are number of forbidden headers for `setRequestHeader` method. You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)

This doc also says,

> Note: The User-Agent header is no longer forbidden, as per spec — see
>   forbidden header name list (this was implemented in Firefox 43) — it
>   can now be set in a Fetch Headers object, or via XHR
>   setRequestHeader().

So if you run it from Firefox 43+, it will not show Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

You will not face this problem if you make the request from your server